# Unable to send email to office 365 via linux command

Tags: linux, centos, sendmail, office365

I am trying to send email via linux command line using following command

```
echo "This is body part" | mail -s "this is subject" username@domain.com
```

If I send to gmail it works but if i send to office365 it does not work.
Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

### User checklist for "non delivered messages"

1. Checked Junk/Spam folder in the receiving mailbox.
2. Check sender mailbox for bounce (delivery problem report) mail messages.
   You may receive first "warning email" after a few hours (e.g. 4h) of failing delivery attempts.
3. Some botched anti-spam system throw away messages "classified as spam" without any hint to the sender or the recipient -> ask admin/postmaster of the receiving mail server

Answer (score 1):

This can also quite often be because of the mail relay server you are using (where the SMTP mail is routing through from the Linux box) not having been set up properly with public RDNS records. Many mail servers reject mail that comes from a domain without the appropriate RDNS configuration.